# Request syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to post some variables to my controller which are then entered into a DB. But i keep getting an error stating that the request is syntactically incorrect.

Here is the form.

```
<form:form  action="addLink" method="POST" commandName="link" >
    <table id="productFinderTable">
        <tbody align="left">
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2">Gender:<input  style="width: 798px;"  type="number" name="gender" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2">Garment:<input  style="width: 798px;"  type="number" name="garment" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2">Product Class:<input  style="width: 798px;"  type="number" name="productclass" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2">Sport:<input  style="width: 798px;"  type="text" name="sport" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2">Link:<input  style="width: 798px;"  type="text" name="link" value="http://www.google.ie" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form:form>
```

The Entity Link

```
package com.wlgore.webapp.fab.pfsa.db;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LINK")
public class Link implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    private String hash;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String link;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private Integer garment;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private Integer productclass;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private Integer gender;

    @Column
    private String sport;

    /**
     * @return the link
     */
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    /**
     * @param link the link to set
     */
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    /**
     * @return the garment
     */
    public Integer getGarment() {
        return garment;
    }

    /**
     * @param garment the garment to set
     */
    public void setGarment(Integer garment) {
        this.garment = garment;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productclass
     */
    public Integer getProductclass() {
        return productclass;
    }

    /**
     * @param productclass the productclass to set
     */
    public void setProductclass(Integer productclass) {
        this.productclass = productclass;
    }

    /**
     * @return the gender
     */
    public Integer getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param gender the gender to set
     */
    public void setGender(Integer gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sport
     */
    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }

    /**
     * @param sport the sport to set
     */
    public void setSport(String sport) {
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    /**
     * @return the hash
     */
    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    /**
     * @param hash the hash to set
     */
    public void setHash(String hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addLink", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addNewCommand(@ModelAttribute("link") Link link,   BindingResult result)throws Exception{

        /***
         * Here we receive the relvant variables 1.Gender 2.Garment 3.Product
         * Class 4.Sport 5.Link
         * */

        try {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid post!");
            } else {
                String hash = HashFunction.gen(8);
                Link linkExists = dao.getById(hash);
                while (null != linkExists) {
                    hash = HashFunction.gen(8);
                    linkExists = dao.getById(hash);
                }
            System.out.println(hash);
            link.setHash(hash);
            dao.create(link);
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString("Test Message");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new ErrorJSON(e));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set your log level to DEBUG and check the logs.

Comment: Can you post the exact error as well as the generated SQL (set `hibernate.show_sql` to `true` in your configuration, or see [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html))?

Comment: You're submitting the form as is? Or changing any of the values? You have `type="number"` for some of those, but if you used javascript or something to change that, Spring will fail to convert it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don’t think `@ModelAttribute` is the correct annotation here. For `BindingResult` to work, you also need `@Valid` on the form bean.

Comment: Where would they use `@RequestParam`?

Comment: Nowhere. Still, you need `@Valid` for `BindingResult` to be filled automatically.